# Icons not shown in React Navigation DrwaerNavigator

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I'm trying to add icons to the below simple [React Navigation DrawerNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html):

```
  export default createAppContainer(createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    icon: 'home'
  },
  Screen1: {
    screen: Screen1
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2
  },
  Screen3: {
    screen: Screen3
  },
}));
```

The drawer is shown fine but icon isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have imported react native vector icons to use icons in your Any Component.

```
 import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
    export default createAppContainer(createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: () => <Ionicons name="ios-home" size={30} style={{ width: 24 }} 
    color="#000" />
    }
    },
    Screen1: {
    screen: Screen1
    },
    Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2
    },
      Screen3: {
    screen: Screen3
      },
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The icon needs to be a component like `<Image>` or `<View>` , not a string .

Comment: Thanks! using component like <Image> works just fine